# Search for all elements in a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

With the updated code below, my search is working, but only using the last word in the Array. Is there a way to search the MySQL column using all words the user inputted?

Note: All input sanitization and escaping is completed in my code but not shown here.

I have two PHP arrays: $search_exploded (user inputted search terms) and $metaphoneArr (metaphones of keywords in MySQL).

I'm cycling through $search_exploded and $metaphoneArr, and if the Levenshtein is less than 2, then I'm adding the metaphone element to a third array called $levenResultsArr.

In MySQL, I'm joining two tables, and if there's a result in my third array ($levenResultsArr) that matches a row in my metaphone_col, then I want the results printed.  Somehow, though, I am not referencing the third array correctly in the MySQL statement.

Any advice?  Here is part of my PHP code.

```
$levenResultsArr = array();
foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each => $searchWord) {
    $search_each2 = metaphone($searchWord);
    echo $search_each2 . "<br/>";

    foreach ($metaphoneArr as $metaword => $val) {
        $lev = levenshtein($search_each2, $val);
        if ($lev < 2) {
            array_push($levenResultsArr, $search_each2);
        }
    }

}

// And shown below is the MySQL statement

$constructs = "
    SELECT vt.idvideolist,
           vt.videotitle,
           vt.videodescription
      FROM videolist_tbl vt
     INNER JOIN keyword__video k2v ON (vt.idvideolist = k2v.video_id)
     INNER JOIN keywords_tbl k ON (k2v.keyword_id = k.idkeywords_tbl)
     WHERE k.metaphone_col = '$search_each2'
";
```

It's only searching using the last word in the array instead of all words in the array.

Comment: Thank you, @YourCommonSense, for editing my newbie PHP syntax. :) This helps me learn a better approach to the syntax that's easier to read. I think I copied/pasted it using my iPad, but I appreciate your help in showing the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that you aren't referencing your array correctly in your query. You are simply referencing the variable `'$search_each2'`. You want to check the entire array. The best way to do this would to be to convert the array to a string using `implode` and using the MySQL `IN` clause. We need to modify the array first to format it correctly:

```
foreach($levenResultsArr as &$foo){
    $foo = "'".$foo."'"; //add single quotes around each object in the array
}
$levenAsStr = implode(",", $levenResultsArr);
```

Then simply change your last line to the following:

```
WHERE k.metaphone_col IN (".$levenAsStr.")";
```

Did this from memory because I'm not in a testing environment, please let me know if there are any syntax errors. Should work for you!

Comment: Thanks, T Martin! This worked for me. :)  The only thing is something must be wrong with my Levenshtein syntax because, for example, when the user input is "lockers" and the db keyword is "locker" the results show nothing (when I know there are three results).  I thought the Levenshtein function would take care of this for me.  It's either my Levenshtein syntax or the "IN" statement maybe?

Comment: T Martin... another problem. If a user enters "free yellow locker" and the keywords "free" and "yellow" are not in the database, but "locker" is in the database, the results of the query show zero results.  I'm assuming this is because using the IN clause it must match all or nothing?

Comment: The IN clause simply checks for a match in the passed in arguments, so it's not all or nothing. To use your example, it will check if something from the database(lets say 'locker') is in the list at any point. In a code format


`SELECT *  FROM Words WHERE 'locker' IN ('free', 'yellow', 'locker')`

That should return information on locker because it is in the list. I would try printing the `$levenAsStr` string after you format it to make sure it looks correct. Also double check that your levenshtein algorithm is correct.

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  I just printed $levenAsStr and it's duplicating each input word many many times into the array.  I guess it's an issue with my foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code its a bit difficult to determine what is going on. A couple of thoughts though.

What var is the array containing all search terms?

I noticed you are pushing items into `$levenResultsArr`. I don't see it being used in the query though.

If it is `$search_each_2` you may try using the `IN` syntax:

`WHERE k.metaphone_col IN '$search_each2';`

This will only match exact values however. i.e.:

`some value` does not return if the `IN` array contains `value`. The array would have to contain `some value`

If you need it to match partial searches you may try using `LIKE` with wildcards: `%`

```
WHERE k.metaphone_col LIKE "%searchTerm1%"
OR k.metaphone_col LIKE "%searchTerm2%"
OR k.metaphone_col LIKE "%searchTerm3%"
```

You could potentially use the `implode` function to create the sql string from the array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Thanks, Shawn.  The var containing all of the user input terms is $search_exploded.  The thing is, I don't know how many search terms a user might enter, so the LIKEs won't work for me.  I explode the user input into the array $search_exploded and cycle through as $search_each.  When I try using $levenResultsArr in the query, nothing happens.